# how to set selected a particular option in angular js . records come from DB

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a problem with angularJs. I want a dropdown to select an option during edit record. I am new to angularJs,lease help me to do this.

HTML Code

```
<select class="form-control" id="txtCities" ng-model='selected' 
       ng-options="c.city_id as c.city_name for c in storesCities">
                    <option></option>
</select>
```

Angular js Code

```
$http.get('StoreCitiesData', {
                params: {
                    pageNumber: page
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.storesCities = response.data.data;
               $scope.selected = { city_id: '410210' };
                console.log(response);
            });
```

Ajax response is like this:

```
{"data":[{"city_id":410115,"city_name":"Angulo"},{"city_id":410210,"city_name":"india"}

{"city_id":410220,"city_name":"pune"},{"city_id":412830,"city_name":"Delhi"}],"pages":1,"page":"1","result":"OK","message":""}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: hi every one i have done this .. thanks for your reply ..

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the following

```
 $scope.selected=410210;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this js file in script files of html, And u can use this in filters

```
       Underscore.js
       http://plnkr.co/edit/8B7vVgT7zU3I1VhrO82I?p=info

       $scope.selectedCityId = '410210';

       $http.get('StoreCitiesData', {
            params: {
                pageNumber: page
            }
       }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.storesCities = response.data.data;
            $scope.selected = 
                  _.filter($scope.storesCities, function (city) {
                      return city.city_id == $scope.selectedCityId;             
                  });
       });
```

And we can use angular.foreach instead of filter

```
       $scope.selectedCityId = '410210';

       $http.get('StoreCitiesData', {
            params: {
                pageNumber: page
            }
       }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.storesCities = response.data.data;
            $scope.selected = 

                  angular.forEach($scope.storesCities, function(city) {
                    if(city.city_id == $scope.selectedCityId)
                    {
                      return city;
                    }
                  });

       });
```